# Quiero saber el nombre español de una herramienta carpintería

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo se llama en español la herramienta de carpintería que se llama “a marking gauge” en inglés?.

Answer (score 5):

**Marking Gauge (En) = Gramil (Esp)**

- "*Marking Gauge* ó scratch gauge". En Inglés ( *Marking* - marca, señal. *Gauge*, de medida, calibre, calibrados.
- En Español, *Gramil*, procedente del griego, escrito «γραμμη» (grammē), que significa, línea, aludiendo el trayecto que se hace con el utensilio.

Es un instrumento tradicional y aún primordial en la carpintería y ebanistería, su función es la de trazar líneas paralelas sobre los distintos ángulos para después realizar el corte.

Existen cuatro clases de Gramiles (Gramiles para madera o de carpintero, Gramil de marcado, Gramil de corte, Gramil de doble punto) También pueden existir para metales..

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta rapida es muy útil.

Answer (score 2):

### Gramil

> Herramienta manual que sirve para trazar líneas paralelas al borde de una pieza a escuadra

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta rapida es muy útil.